# npm stuck on input loop after updating from react-scripts-ts to react-scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

Not really any code for this, essentially used this blog as reference: https://vincenttunru.com/migrate-create-react-app-typescript-to-create-react-app/

basically, the scripts look like this

```
    "scripts": {
        "watch": "npm-watch",
        "build-css": "lessc src/main.less src/index.css",
        "start-js": "react-scripts start",
        "start": "npm-run-all -p watch start-js",
        "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "test:staged": "echo 'write some tests'",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
```

it runs fine up until "npm start" where everything is fine up until this moment:

```
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
? We're unable to detect target browsers.

Would you like to add the defaults to your package.json? (Y/n) n 
Unrecognized input: n

Unrecognized input:
```

where it's this weird loop because input isn't parsing input properly or something, as in I can't even exit because it's detected as an input, so the only way to stop is to shut down the terminal

Answer (score 0):

In the package.json

```
"browserslist": [
    "defaults"
]
```